# 'List index out of range' according to leetcode. But works in IDLE

Tags: python, list, indexing

I'm working on a leetcode problem which asks me to find the longest common prefix, the same letters, among some strings. The language is python3. The problem is as followed. (https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-common-prefix/)

> Write a function to find the longest common prefix string amongst an
>   array of strings.
>
> If there is no common prefix, return an empty string "".
>
> - Example 1:
>
>   Input: `["flower","flow","flight"]`
>
>   Output: `"fl"`
> - Example 2:
>
>   Input: `["dog","racecar","car"]`
>
>   Output: `""`
>
>   Explanation: There is no common prefix among the input strings.

I tried to get the longest string as it must contain all the common letters. To do so I try to get a list of length of the strings and get the longest length. Then I can use the longest length to get the longest string. But a 'list index out of range' bug occurs when I submit my code to leetcode.

```
ls.sort()
lmax = ls[len(ls)-1]
```

I don't see there is a list index range problem here as I have used this method before. Also, I copied the code to IDLE and it didn't report a bug.

The code below is just the first part of my code. The rest of them is just to check for the same letters.

I would be really grateful if anyone could help me with this problem. Thank you.

```
class Solution:
    def longestCommonPrefix(self, x):

        list1 = []
        for element in x: #convert strings into lists to search for common letters
            list1.append(list(element))

        i = 0 #for searching longest string
        m = 0 #for indicating letters in the longest string
        n = 0 #for indicating other strings
        p = 0 #for indicating letters in other strings

        ls = [] #search for the longest string
        for strs in list1:
            ls.append(len(strs))



        ls.sort()
        lmax = ls[len(ls)-1] ###This is the step that the bug occurs.##



        while i <= len(list1)-1: # To get the longest string.
            if len(list1[i]) == lmax:
                break
            else:
                i += 1
        longestStr = list1[i]
```

Comment: Just because it worked for a few test cases in IDLE doesn't mean it will also work for every test case Leetcode can throw at it.

Comment: @DanielQiao have you checked out on what testcase you have this issue? Typically on leetcode when your code fails for some reason the platform will show you what data it tried with your script. Try with that data in your local environment.

Comment: Thank you for helping me edit the problem and your suggestion. I'll go to check the code again to see if there are any other errors I've missed. Thank you very much!

Comment: In idle....try passing in a blank list? A blank list : [][-1] would throw that error.

Comment: @DemetriOS Oh yes that's one of the problems I've mistaken. Thank you very much!

Comment: This solution is way more complicated than it needs to be.  `zip` the input string together and iterate though the zipped strings until theres an unequal character.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Yes I have just encountered other problems after solving this one. I think there are still other errors with my code and I need to work out a better solution than this one. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the bug is where you think it is. The line of code `lmax = ls[len(ls)-1]` will only fail if the list `ls` is empty.  Side note: to get the last element in a list, use a negative index, which starts from the end and counts backward: `lmax = ls[-1]`

So I would double check that `ls` contains strings. Perhaps when switching IDEs, the param `x` isn't being passed in correctly.

Comment: I just added an 'if' line to check for blank lists and it avoided the problem! Thank you very much!